# Play audio again after finished with AVPlayer swift

Tags: swift, avplayer

How to play again the same audio after finished? Now I use this code with AVPlayer:

```
fileprivate func play () {
    guard let url = URL(string: record.recordUrl) else { return }
    let playItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playItem)
    player.play()
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Player finished")
    currentTimeSlider.setValue(0, animated: true)
    currentTimeLabel.text = "00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Player finished")
    currentTimeSlider.setValue(0, animated: true)
    currentTimeLabel.text = "00:00"

    //Swift 4
    player.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)

    //Swift 2 & 3 (I believe for 2 & 3)
    //player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)

    //Play
    player.play()
}
```

I added the seek back to the beginning (the tolerance makes sure it is exactly at zero, and not around zero with some margin of error).

Also added the feature to play when done.

Comment: Unfortunately I've got an error `Type 'CMTime' has no member 'zero'`

Comment: Which Swift version are you using? 2, 3, 4?

Comment: My version is 4

Comment: Swift 4 has `CMTime` where `CMTime.zero` is a legitimate value. Swift 2 & 3 has `CMTime Zero` as `kCMTimeZero`

Comment: You should be importing AVKit. However, I'm assuming you already have it imported, since you are using either AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer. Here, you can see that it is a legitimate variable. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime/1400875-zero

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes I have imported AVKit).

Comment: If it is the correct answer, make sure to make it so!

Comment: I did it with this strange way `let zero = CMTime(seconds: 0.0, preferredTimescale: 1)
        
        player.seek(to: zero, toleranceBefore: zero, toleranceAfter: zero)`

Comment: @StanislavPutilov that error, explained in the edit